# How to let ViewModel trigger View update

Tags: wpf, mvvm, charts, syncfusion

I need real time charting (100-200ms updates) of a maximum of 20 series. After some research I settled on syncfusion because I can use the community license and at first sight it seems performant. The only drawback seems to be the sometimes lacky MVVM support.

To get a good realtime performance I found this blog post:
https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/Deliver-high-performance-charts-with-Syncfusions-WPF-chart-control.aspx

I'm especially interested in the 'batch update' section because all 20 series will get updated at the same time, there's no need to rerender the chart 20 times.

An alternative seems to be this: http://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/sfchart/how-to/add-range-of-points-dynamically
I have yet to investigate the differences.

But how can I make this MVVM friendly.

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

This requirement can be achieved by accessing the SfChart control from its view(UserControl) which was initialized in the ViewModel class, to have access on SuspendNotification and ResumeNotification methods in SfChart.
Real time updates can be achieved in two ways.

1. By using auto-scrolling feature, to maintain a fixed amount point in view while real time update and also there is a provision to view old data through scrolling.
2. By removing the first record from the collection while adding new record at the end. 
   Demo Samples : [Real_Update_Samples](https://transfer.pcloud.com/download.html?code=5ZeEzYZanFkS7z7eqHZjKh0ZCY4mDbiFBT0Xv3wOvsL9W452RuPX)